# How to securely update to a mainline kernel? (no http)

Tags: kernel, updates

Here [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade) . I learned how to update to a mainline kernel, but the download is in plain HTTP.

How do I update my kernel securely? Is there signed way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainline kernel are installed manually, and same thing for signing. It could be verified manually.

They provide both: `CHECKSUMS` and signed `CHECKSUMS.gpg` file by *Kernel PPA `<kernel-ppa@canonical.com>`*.

Procedure is well documented in [Ubuntu Wiki - Mainline Builds, Verifying the mainline build binaries](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds#Verifying_the_mainline_build_binaries).